# Multiple SurfaceView Threads, Crashing in Android Fragments

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments, surfaceview

I wrote this dynamic keyboard app to track frequencies in an online PowerBall-type game. I used a SurfaceView because I can do stuff in real-time that I can't do with Buttons.  The app works great with one thread: onPause destroys the surface/thread and onResume creates the surface/thread again. I thought that it would be cool to add another keyboard in a Tabbed View fragment so the user can track the keno numbers as well. For example

Fragment1:

```
    return new PowerBallPanel(getActivity(),15,3);
```

Fragment2:

```
    return new PowerBallPanel(getActivity(),75,5);
```

I thought Fragments were very similar to individual apps but every time I add Fragment2 I get a Surface Locked Exception, even though it's not running yet.

I am confused.

Thanks.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to include the Thread class as a sub-class of the surfaceview class.  Hope this helps someone else.